# Rails, ActiveRecord, and PSQL: Saving an array to column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am trying to save an entire array to a column using PSQL and ActiveRecord but having issues saving the array.

My migration:

```
add_column :mashups, :youtube_ids, :string, array: true, default: []
```

My model:

```
class Mashup < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :youtube_ids
```

Creating an instance:

```
movie_array = ["abc", "def", "ghi"]
@mashup = Mashup.new(youtube_ids: movie_array)
```

But instance doesn't save the array:

```
@mashup.youtube_ids => []
```

I am able to add one string at a time:

```
@mashup.youtube_ids << movie_array.first
@mashup.youtube_ids => ["abc"]
```

But how can I add them all at once?

Comment: You don't need serialize if you're using an array column

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work if I remove this part from the migration:

```
 array: true, default: []
```